# Limit the min/max of pensize() in turtle

Tags: python, max, turtle-graphics, minimum

The pen size stays the same size when I press the - and + keys, as I draw with turtle.

I reworked the problem using some plausible answers, but to no avail. I looked on the internet for a similar solution and came up empty-handed.

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(400,500)                # Determine the window size
wn = turtle.Screen()                 # Get a reference to the window
wn.title("Handling keypresses!")     # Change the window title
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")             # Set the background color
tess = turtle.Turtle()               # Create our favorite turtle

# The next four functions are our "event handlers".
def h1():
    tess.forward(30)

def h2():
    tess.left(45)

def h3():
    tess.right(45)

def h4():
    tess.color("red")

def h5():
    tess.color("green")

def h6():
    tess.color("blue")

def h7():
    tess.pensize(0)

def h8():
    tess.pensize(20)

def h9():
    wn.bye()                        # Close down the turtle window

def h10():
    tess.backward(30)



# These lines "wire up" keypresses to the handlers we've defined.
wn.onkey(h1, "Up")
wn.onkey(h2, "Left")
wn.onkey(h3, "Right")
wn.onkey(h4, "r")
wn.onkey(h5, "g")
wn.onkey(h6, "b")
wn.onkey(h7, "-")
wn.onkey(h8, "+")
wn.onkey(h9, "q")
wn.onkey(h10, "Down")

# Now we need to tell the window to start listening for events,
# If any of the keys that we're monitoring is pressed, its
# handler will be called.
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to use the .pensize() method in turtle to increase/decrease its thickness between a restricted range of 0 and 20 using the - and + keys by function with the .onkey() method. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `h7()` and `h8()` change the pensize to 0 and 20 as intended?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a global variable to track the pen size.  Turtles are already (effectively) global entities and know their own pen size (tested code):

```
def h7():
    pensize = tess.pensize() - 1

    if pensize >= 0:
        tess.pensize(pensize)

def h8():
    pensize = tess.pensize() + 1

    if pensize <= 20:
        tess.pensize(pensize)
```

However, there's another issue that will keep this, or any solution, from working correctly.  This code:

```
wn.onkey(h7, "-")
wn.onkey(h8, "+")
```

Needs to instead be:

```
wn.onkey(h7, "minus")
wn.onkey(h8, "plus")
```

Otherwise, the `"-"` symbol will cause all unassigned keys (including shift key needed to type `"+"`) to invoke the `h7()` handler!  This change should also allow the equivalent keys on the keypad to work.  Complete code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

wn = Screen()  # Get a reference to the window
wn.setup(400, 500)  # Determine the window size
wn.title("Handling keypresses!")  # Change the window title
wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")  # Set the background color

tess = Turtle()  # Create our favorite turtle

# The next nine functions are our "event handlers".
def h1():
    tess.forward(30)

def h2():
    tess.left(45)

def h3():
    tess.right(45)

def h4():
    tess.color("red")

def h5():
    tess.color("green")

def h6():
    tess.color("blue")

def h7():
    pensize = tess.pensize() - 1

    if pensize >= 0:
        tess.pensize(pensize)

def h8():
    pensize = tess.pensize() + 1

    if pensize <= 20:
        tess.pensize(pensize)

def h9():
    tess.backward(30)

# These lines "wire up" keypresses to the handlers we've defined.
wn.onkey(h1, "Up")
wn.onkey(h2, "Left")
wn.onkey(h3, "Right")
wn.onkey(h4, "r")
wn.onkey(h5, "g")
wn.onkey(h6, "b")
wn.onkey(h7, "minus")
wn.onkey(h8, "plus")
wn.onkey(h9, "Down")
wn.onkey(wn.bye, "q")  # Close down the turtle window

# Now we need to tell the window to start listening for events,
# If any of the keys that we're monitoring is pressed, its
# handler will be called.
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had no idea I needed to use words instead of characters for the on key bindings! It really surprised me, because I never suspected that was part of the error.